# onActivityResult in fragment not called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, whatsapp

I am trying to attach an image on whatsapp through my app. My app contains two activities
A: It contains many fragments
B: Just an activity

When I had put an intent filter on my Mainactivity which contains fragments for picking images. So here is what happens:

Tried to attach an picture to whatsapp -> Open Mainactivity(Fragment1) Click on Gridview Item -> Goes to Activity B

When I click on button in B to send the data back to Whatsapp, it went back to Mainactivity which doesn't even call Fragment's OnActivityResult method. I have to send data back to whatsapp.
I have looked into every question related to this problem. But nothing works! :/

Code I am using:

Mainactivity.java(that contains fragments)

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Fragment1.java

```
    mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(

              new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("im",fileList);
                i.putExtra("pos", position);
                i.putExtra("folder", folder);
                i.putExtra("req", isinint);
                startActivityForResult(i, Activity.RESULT_OK);


        }

    });
```

Fragment1.java(Onactivityresult)

```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    Log.i("called","called");
                 getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                 getActivity().finish();
           }


}
```

Activity B:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Log.i("called","btncalled");

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Smileys/" + imageUrls[pagerPosition].replace("assets://pics/", ""))); 

                FullImageActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, shareIntent); //set the file/intent as result
                FullImageActivity.this.finish(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: I can't see an error in your code above. I suggest you to do some changes:
1 - Create a constant with your requestCode, (for example: `private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_PICTURE = 1;`) and use it when you call startActivityForResult instead of Activity.RESULT_OK
2 - Check that your main activity receives a call to onActivityResult using Log
3 - Check if other fragment is receiving this return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `Activity.RESULT_OK` as a request code. That's a result code.
Change the request code, something like "123" or something, I don't know.

Then, secondly:

- inside `FullImageActivity.class`, make sure you build your `Intent` with the stuff that you need, and then you call

  ```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent();
  myIntent.putExtra("your_stuff_here");
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntent);
  finish();
  ```

so that your code execution returns the result to the fragment that called it.

- inside your caller fragment `(Fragment1)` make the call to `super` as last thing. Something like this:

  ```
  @Override 
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
   if(requestCode == "123" && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
   Log.i("called","called");
   //add your logic here
   } 
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the requestcode Activity.OK to some number and It worked!